# What's the difference between .get and .get() while ordering data?

Tags: python

I know 3 different methods to order data: .sort(), sorted(), key=itemgetter().
But while studying through ChatGPT I met this other one that consists in giving .get as a key. I don't get themeaning of It though. .get() is usually used to get the value of a key. By intution... If I don't explicit any key, I guess It returns a list of values and then prints the corresponding key. How? And why It doesn't accept any keys inside the .get function?
Also, hat's the difference between the first two lines of code and the last two?

```
c = {'hello, world!': 4, 'dfjhg': 1, 'hello, world': 7}
print(max(c))

c = {'hello, world!': 4, 'dfjhg': 1, 'hello, world': 7}
print(max(c, key=c.get))
```

Answer (score 2):

In `max(c, key=c.get)` the argument key is a callable that will be called on every item of the given iterables and use this as the value to sort on

Use `c.get` means exactly the same as `lambda x: c.get(x)`, it's just shorter

---

- `max(c)` will return the highest key, in lexicographical order, so the further, ie `hello, world!`
- `max(c, key=c.get)` will return the key having the biggest value, so `hello, world`

---

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
mappings = {1: 10, 2: 8, 3: 50, 4: 4}
print(max(values))  # 4, highest item of values
print(max(values, key=mappings.get))  # 3, item of values with the highest value in mapping
```

Answer (score 0):

`dict.get` is always used to get the single value associated with a key (or a default). The `key` parameter is required. If `max` tried to call it without a parameter, an exception would be raised. When you call

```
max(c, c.get)
```

`max` iterates the keys of `c`. But you included a function to convert each key to some other value to use for the comparison. So, for each key, `max` calls `c.get` once, getting the value for that key.

The result is the key whose value is the maxiumn.